# Create Event Listener for Responses on Guzzle6

Tags: php, api, laravel, guzzle

I'm doing request to api with Guzzle 6. I want catch `HTTP 1.0 401 Unauthorized` exception and retry request after get new token. But I can not find examples in the new version documentation.

Events interface had in the old documentation but no event interface new version.

**I'm using code this for made request;**

```
public function doSearch(Request $request)
{
    $apiData = API::where('id', '1')->first(['api_url', 'api_key']);
    try {
        $client = new Client([
            // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri'  =>  $apiData['api_url'],
            'timeout'   =>  60,
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' =>  'bearer token',
                'Content-Type'  =>  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
            'verify'    => false,
        ]);

        $request = $client->request('POST', '/api/booking/ticket/search', [
            'RouteType' => $request->input('type')
        ]);
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        die((string)$e->getResponse()->getBody());
    }
    $code = $request->getStatusCode(); // 200
    $test = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    //$test = json_decode($test,true);
    return view('front.searchresult');
}
```

I don't want catch with try-catch code block. I should to renew my desire to create an event listener.

How to catch HTTP Exception and renew request on Guzzle 6?

Comment: You can create your custom handler stack without the HTTP errors, like here: https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/blob/master/src/Client.php#L78-L82